# Subtle definition of 喜欢

Tags: grammar

喜欢她就主动一点儿， 机会是不回自己跑到你面前的。

I ran into such sentence and had trouble understanding 喜欢她就主动一点儿。

Does this mean, I would prefer she acts more proactively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One correction from the original sentence:

> 喜欢她就主动一点儿， 机会是不 **会** 自己跑到你面前的。

It means: *if you like her, you should be proactive / take initiatives, since chances wouldn't run for you automatically(implying she wouldn't call you first).*

The sentence can be paraphrased as: 如果你喜欢她，你就主动一点儿， 机会是不会自己跑到你面前的。